# Backup and restore Azure database programmatically with smo

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, azure, smo

We have a running web application. Everything is hosted on azure. 
We have one sql server and two databases: production and test.
Client requested functionality to backup production db and restore it in place of test db. I am using following code:

```
    public static void BackupDatabase(string databaseName, string userName, string password, string serverName, string destinationPath)
    {
        try
        {
            Backup sqlBackup = new Backup();

            sqlBackup.Action = BackupActionType.Database;
            sqlBackup.BackupSetDescription = "ArchiveDataBase:" + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
            sqlBackup.BackupSetName = "Archive";

            sqlBackup.Database = databaseName;

            BackupDeviceItem deviceItem = new BackupDeviceItem(destinationPath, DeviceType.File);
            ServerConnection connection = new ServerConnection(serverName, userName, password);
            Server sqlServer = new Server(connection);

            Database db = sqlServer.Databases[databaseName];

            sqlBackup.Initialize = true;
            sqlBackup.Checksum = true;
            sqlBackup.ContinueAfterError = true;

            sqlBackup.Devices.Add(deviceItem);
            sqlBackup.Incremental = false;

            sqlBackup.ExpirationDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(3);
            sqlBackup.LogTruncation = BackupTruncateLogType.Truncate;

            sqlBackup.FormatMedia = false;

            sqlBackup.SqlBackup(sqlServer);
        }
        catch (FailedOperationException ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
        catch(ConnectionFailureException ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }

    public static void RestoreDatabase(string databaseName, string filePath, string serverName, string userName, string password, string dataFilePath, string logFilePath)
    {
        try
        {
            Restore sqlRestore = new Restore();

            BackupDeviceItem deviceItem = new BackupDeviceItem(filePath, DeviceType.File);
            sqlRestore.Devices.Add(deviceItem);
            sqlRestore.Database = databaseName;

            ServerConnection connection = new ServerConnection(serverName, userName, password);
            Server sqlServer = new Server(connection);

            Database db = sqlServer.Databases[databaseName];

            db.Drop();

            sqlRestore.Action = RestoreActionType.Database;
            string dataFileLocation = dataFilePath + databaseName + ".mdf";
            string logFileLocation = logFilePath + databaseName + "_Log.ldf";
            db = sqlServer.Databases[databaseName];
            RelocateFile rf = new RelocateFile(databaseName, dataFileLocation);

            System.Data.DataTable logicalRestoreFiles = sqlRestore.ReadFileList(sqlServer);
            sqlRestore.RelocateFiles.Add(new RelocateFile(logicalRestoreFiles.Rows[0][0].ToString(), dataFileLocation));
            sqlRestore.RelocateFiles.Add(new RelocateFile(logicalRestoreFiles.Rows[1][0].ToString(), logFileLocation));

            sqlRestore.SqlRestore(sqlServer);
            db = sqlServer.Databases[databaseName];
            db.SetOnline();
            sqlServer.Refresh();
        }
        catch(ExecutionFailureException ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Everything works locally and on all virtual machines. But now we have everything on Azure and I have no idea what backup directory should I set. It must be directory on server to which sqlclient (probably azure sql client) has access. Same thing goes when it comes to provide location during restoring database to test database.

How to get access to directories where backup can be stored and where mdf and log files can be saved?

Kind regards

Comment: [Different ways to Backup your Windows Azure SQL Database](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mast/2013/03/03/different-ways-to-backup-your-windows-azure-sql-database/)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response but those solutions aren't really what I need. Those are approaches to backup database either from sql management studio or azure portal. I need a solution to back up database from the service written in c#.

Comment: Hi @damianchmielewski Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: Actually I did. I create backup and save it in Azure blob storage. I will provide code here soon.

Comment: @damianchmielewski how did you solve this , it would help if you post your solution

Comment: @damianchmielewski - still waiting for the sample code of your solution :)

Comment: Come on @damianchmielewski it's been almost three years, we are all waiting here!