# Attach SQL Database from Local server directory using SMO

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, database, smo

I am looking a workaround to attach MDF File from the server local directory(c:\data) using SMO in C#.net. it works fine when we attach the database through shared path(\\server1\data). 
Any support is highly appreciated.

My current implementation looks like

```
private static Server GetServerInstance(string Server)
{
    //string ConString = string.Format("server='{0}';Trusted_Connection=yes", serverName);
    string connectionString = string.Format("data source={0};initial catalog=master;integrated security=True;", Server);
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    ServerConnection serverConnection = new ServerConnection(connection);
    Server mServer = new Server(serverConnection);
    if(mServer!=null)
    {
        mServer.ConnectionContext.Connect();
        SetServerStatementTimeOut(mServer);
    }
    return mServer;
}

Server mServer = GetServerInstance(server);

mServer.AttachDatabase(databaseName, new StringCollection {
    "\\server1\data\tempDB.mdf",
    "\\server1\data\tempdb.ldf"
}, AttachOptions.None);
```

Comment: Do you have permission to write to the c:\ drive (or subfolder data)?  Is the database already loaded?  I have found when you deattach a database you need to close your c# application before reattach.

Comment: Just to add more it says "path not found" when i tried with the local server drive(C:\data), i think it is trying to find the path from where i am executing the APP. it will be resolved if i somehow tell the SMO library to use the server path drive but not sure how can we achieve it.

Comment: The requirements for attaching says the file must be a drive the server (physically mounted on the PC that contains the SQL Server software).   So use FILE COPY to copy file from c: drive to server drive.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback.I have already copied the file on the server local drive(C:\drive) using shared path. I am using File.copy function to the mdf and ldf files

Comment: The read/write properties of the mdf/ldf files could be wrong.  If you use archive the properties get set to admin.  That why it is recommended not to archive.  Instead deattach and then make copy in windows. I suspect the read/write properties of the c\: drive is wrong while the shared path is correct since they are both pointing to the same location.

Comment: I set back the right permission after copy. I have seen similar problem discussed at below link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38315156/backup-and-restore-azure-database-programmatically-with-smo